# Delete Data from the cell an Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am building a chat app as a learning journey for ios programming.The app is using firebase for the authentication etc.I am trying to implement the delete feature with _comit editingstyle method.But I am not able to delete the data from firebase.When I logout and log in back, am able to see the the old message. My understanding, I have to select the child corresponding to the cell index.I tried multiple combinations with observe set to .childremoved, .value but nothing works . i would appreciate any help and explanations .

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

var messageArray : [Message] = [Message]()
  var postkey = ""



@IBOutlet var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var sendButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var messageTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var messageTableView: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // declare delegate
    messageTableView.delegate = self
    messageTableView.dataSource = self
    messageTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MessageCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customMessageCell")



    messageTextfield.delegate = self


    ref = Database.database().reference()


    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TableViewTapped))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    retrieveMessages()
}

// TableViewTapped method
@objc func TableViewTapped () {
    view.endEditing(true)
}


// TODO: Data source method

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let  groupeRef = ref.child("message").child((messageArray[indexPath.row].messageBody))
        groupeRef.removeValue()
        messageArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        print(indexPath.row)

        messageTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)


    }
    messageTableView.reloadData()


}
```

Message Class

```
class Message {
    //TODO: Messages need a messageBody and a sender variable

    var messageBody = ""
    var sender = ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code and make sure with child key:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    if editingStyle == .delete {

      self.ref.child("message").child((messageArray[indexPath.row].messageBody)).removeValue { error, _ in

             print(error)   
          }
        messageArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        print(indexPath.row)

        messageTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)


    }
    messageTableView.reloadData()


}
```

Check your database in console for updated value.

Comment: It deletes the whole DB, instead of the child corresponding to the cell.

Comment: @Vangola please try my updated answer if it can't delete child then please print key child and also re-check hierarchy and make change child reference according because this is the simple way of delete child from firebase realtime db.

Comment: I used your updated code and added print(self.child("Message").key) gives optional("Message") on the console. The code does not delete the child corresponding to cell from the tableView.Nothing happen on the firebase .

Comment: Then it should be work good according my updated answer and please check it in console according. :)

Comment: Sorry I cannot use the chat . I am new on stack . Don't have enough reputation. Thanks

Comment: Yes I can understand. Finally I have tried to help you with my best knowledge and thank you so much for discussion. if you need more guidance please follow this tutorial : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write